# What is the meaning of Neighbor Mr. Robutusen words?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-princess-diaries

In [**The Princess Diaries**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0247638/) (2001), what is the meaning of Mr. Robutusen words (say to himself):

> Mr. Robutusen: The elegant European woman didn't stay for tea.
>
> Mia: Thanks (to Joe who opens the car's door for her)
>
> Mr. Robutusen: **But the promise of tomorrow hung in the air.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially it means that Mr Robutusen liked/was impressed by/was attracted to Clarisse when he met her.

Although she's left today there is the possibility he might see her again **tomorrow (or at least in the future)** and that's something he looks forward to.

It may also be a quote from an [**unsourced poem**](https://www.scrapbook.com/poems/doc/12349.html) but only the first couple of lines are apt.

> **The promise of tomorrow**
>
> **and the hope of dreams come true...**